# How set a SupportMapFragment (replace fragment) in a NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, supportmapfragment

I have a navigation drawer and I want to open a map when the user click in the button. problem is I can not replace the current fragment and set my SupportMapFragment. I think SupportMapFragment is a fragment as well, but I have to be wrong. What I'm doing wrong? and how can I fix it?

**Class Map**

```
public class Map extends SupportMapFragment {

private GoogleMap map;

//Position
public static final LatLng TEMPORALPOSITION = new LatLng(4.667184, -74.059463);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    map = getMap();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(TEMPORALPOSITION));

}
```

}

**onNavigationDrawerItemSelected function**

```
    @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Stations();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Favorites();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Map();
            break;
    }

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

In the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected function is where I have the problem.

Below you can see my fragment **map.xml** maybe it can help.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Thanks!!

**Edited:**

I have change the android:name attribute in my xml.. but I still having the main problem. Take a look the screen show is below.

[image: I can't do that]

Comment: do you solve the problem ?
I have the same issue right now :(

Answer (score 0):

The `android:name` attribute in your xml is incorrect. It should be:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Try fixing that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look tonight after work. I let you know if its ok.

Comment: I still having the problem... do you know how can I fix it? or maybe I'm trying something it's not possible. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh. you probably don't want Map to extent `SupportmapFragment` Instead, you want it to extend `MapFragment`

Comment: let me explain you. I have a navigation drawer and what I want it's open a map when the user click on the map tab. when a user clicks in a tab I replace always a fragment so thats What I need. I'm using the SupportmapFragment because I have suppose it will support by a fragment.. but not. so any way to replace a fragment a show a map??

Comment: you can see the image I have added. I set the value of the object 'fragment' and then fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();